# Linux application to install Windows on a USB drive

Tags: windows, windows-xp

There are everal applications which can install MS Windows on a USB drive, but all of these applications should be installed in a Windows environment. I am an Ubuntu user and do not have a Windows environment to install these applications, which can make a bootable Windows USB.

Is there a linux (Ubuntu) application for install Windows XP from ISO file on a USB drive? To build a bootable Windows USB.

Answer (score 0):

winusb

to install winusb run the below commands in terminal

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install winusb

Comment: I read about WinUSB, but it says `usb stick windows installer`. I don't need an installer, I need a bootable Windows on USB (as we install independent linux on a USB). Is the final product a bootable Windows (or just an installer)?

Comment: do you mean running windows without install this link may help http://betanews.com/2014/01/13/run-windows-8-or-8-1-directly-from-a-usb-drive-on-any-computer-for-free/

Comment: or u can download a portable virtual box and install it in usb drive and then install windows in it

Comment: yes, installing on USB instead of HDD. In your link, the application needed is `Aomei Partition Assistant Standard`, which is a Windows application. I am looking for a similar application which can be installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: i tried it once but didnt find any software for that but found a method to extract the windows iso to the pendrive to run windows from pendrive but its extremely slow so i dropped that thought just found relative article here http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/47621-Install-Windows-7-on-an-USB-stick-or-External-HDD

Answer (score 0):

Proceedure:

Obtain 64 or 128GB USB3 flash drive.
Use mkusb to create a persistent flash drive with 1% persistence.
Safely remove and replug flash drive.
Copy existing virtual machine image, (.vdi), to the "usbdata" partition on the flash drive.
Reboot into the USB
Connect to internet.
In Software & Updates, check "Software restricted by ..., etc.", then select "Updates" and ensure the machine will not will not automatically download or install updates.
In Software Center install VirtualBox,
From www.virtualbox.org/wiki/downloads download the extension pack.
Install the extension pack using VBox.
Run VBox and select New, when you get to Hard disk, select "Use an existing..." and choose the image in usbdata.

Results:

So far the drive is working in every computer I try, but very, very slowly in computers without USB3 and/or less than 4GB RAM.
In a computer with lots of RAM some things almost seem faster, like orbiting complex rendered solids in AutoCAD.
AutoCAD 2013 & 2016, SolidWorks, Cosmos FEA, Staad, Autoplant, Rhino and SketchUp all work
Hilti Profis required a new serial number, and CAESAR II and CADWorx required reinstallation of hardware locks.
Have had no luck connecting to a VPN.